# Drupal node / data import issue

Tags: mysql, drupal, import, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a client who needs to have data imported into drupal from a large spreadsheet.  They already had the modules setup and I have the data all in the right tables... so it seems.  I have run my own custom scripts to manipulate what was in the spreadsheets and exported / imported it into the drupal databases.

However, when I go to view that type of content in the backend, it shows there are multiple pages of data but displays "No content available." in every page.  Here are the tables I imported to:

```
// for the business listing node type
field_data_field_bd_address_city
field_data_field_bd_address_street
field_data_field_bd_address_zip
field_data_field_bd_business_type
field_data_field_bd_contact_email
field_data_field_bd_contact_name
field_data_field_bd_description
field_data_field_bd_image
field_data_field_bd_listing_type
field_data_field_bd_phone
field_data_field_bd_tags
field_data_field_bd_website

// drupal default tables
node
node_comment_statistics
taxonomy_index
taxonomy_term_data
taxonomy_term_hierarchy
taxonomy_vocabulary
```

Am I missing any tables that I need to import data into to make connections?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before and it took me a while to solve it. This was before anyone had mentioned the feeds module to me so I thought it was my only option.

If you're going to upload straight into your database you need to enter the data into the revisions tables as well. So you would have:

```
// for the business listing node type
field_data_field_bd_address_city
field_data_field_bd_address_street
field_data_field_bd_address_zip
field_data_field_bd_business_type
field_data_field_bd_contact_email
field_data_field_bd_contact_name
field_data_field_bd_description
field_data_field_bd_image
field_data_field_bd_listing_type
field_data_field_bd_phone
field_data_field_bd_tags
field_data_field_bd_website
```

And also:

```
// for the business listing node type
field_revision_field_bd_address_city
field_revision_field_bd_address_street
field_revision_field_bd_address_zip
field_revision_field_bd_business_type
field_revision_field_bd_contact_email
field_revision_field_bd_contact_name
field_revision_field_bd_description
field_revision_field_bd_image
field_revision_field_bd_listing_type
field_revision_field_bd_phone
field_revision_field_bd_tags
field_revision_field_bd_website
```

The same goes for the node table. This took me a while to work out and worked for me. Typically someone then mentioned the feeds module which would have saved me time but I thought I'd share what worked for me.

Comment: I figured it out, answer below

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually importing the data directly into the database and trying to figure out how to satisfy all the relational dependencies to make it work, I would suggest using the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds)

If you wish to continue with the manual process, perhaps [this ER diagram](http://upsitesweb.com/sites/upsites.co/files/drupal7_model_0.png) of the Drupal database will help (keep in mind it is a bit dated and was likely based on earlier versions of Drupal 7).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this.  I installed the Feeds Module, but am running into issues with it not letting me enable it.  This is my first time working with Drupal so I am very lost.  I checked the ER Diagram as well, thanks for that.  I feel like I'm making all the right connections but I just can't figure it out

Comment: @DrewBartlett did you check to make sure all the other modules that Feeds depends on are also installed?

Comment: I figured it out, answer below

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to add data to the node_revision table with status of 1 set to all the nodes and it worked out just fine after that!

Comment: Do the fields work as well or is it just the node showing up?

Comment: The fields work, display, and all show up correctly associated with the terms!

Comment: Interesting. I had a nightmare with data importing to Drupal.

Comment: yeah it was pretty awful how it all went, but hey it's all over now!